# I can differentiate between months using pairs in R

Tags: r

```
    data(airquality)
a=airquality

convert_fahr_to_kelvin <- function(temp) {
     kelvin <- ((temp - 32) * (5 / 9)) + 273.15
     return(kelvin)
}
a[,4]=
convert_fahr_to_kelvin(a[,4])
oz=a[,1]
sr=a[,2]
wv=a[,3]
te=a[,4]
pairs(~oz+sr+wv+te,
col = c("orange") , 
      pch = c(18),
      labels = c("Ozono", "Irradiancia Solar", "Velocidad del viento","Temperatura"), 
      main = "Diagramas de dispersión por parejas")
```

[This is the graphic that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjSAd.png)

This is what i am doing but, actually i would like to differentiate between months, like 31 first numbers of my a matrix, from all columns, be color green, for example and this for each month, i tried to separate the numbers in groups using group:

```
    group <- NA
group[sr[1:31]]<-1
group[sr[32:61]]<-2
group[sr[62:92]]<-3
group[sr[93:123]]<-4
group[sr[124:153]]<-5

group[sr[1:31]]
group[sr[32:61]]
group[sr[62:92]]
group[sr[93:123]]
group[sr[124:153]]
```

[here the numbers repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6BAy.png)

But what i get is that if the numbers in each column are the same they get in the same group, and i have been trying to solve it in other ways but i don't finally get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to create a group with `gl`

```
group <- as.integer(gl(length(sr), 31, length(sr)))
table(group)
#group
#1  2  3  4  5 
#31 31 31 31 29
```

---

In the OP's code, 'group' is initialized as `NA` of length 1. Then, it is assigned based on values of 'sr' instead of just

```
group <- integer(length(sr))
group[1:31] <- 1
group[32:61] <- 2
  ...
```

whereas if we use `sr` values as index

```
sr[1:31]
#[1] 190 118 149 313  NA  NA 299  99  19 194  NA 256 290 274  65 334 307  78 322  44   8 320  25  92  66 266  NA  13 252 223 279
```

then group values that are changed to 1 are at positions 190, 118, 149, 313, ....